# ORACLE SQL: LIKE to CONTAINS

Tags: sql, oracle

I am desperate to change LIKE to CONTAINS function (last WHERE expression) in this query(below). It works good with LIKE, but when I change LIKE to CONTAINS then I get error, I spent many hours trying to fix it. The error is:

> [42000][979] ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Query is:

```
select id, 
       agr_numbers,
               vehicle_reg_numbers
            FROM (
            select id 
                   ,(select listagg(column_value, ', ') within group (order by column_value) from table(coll_names)) as agr_numbers
                   ,vehicle_reg_numbers
           ,event_date_sortable
            from (
              select clme.id
            ,clme.vehicle_reg_numbers
                    ,collect(distinct nvl(agr.agreement_number,cea.agreement_number)) as coll_names
            ,clme.event_date_sortable
                FROM 
                v_clm_event_list clme
                LEFT JOIN adm_address adr ON clme.aav_adm_address_id = adr.id
                    LEFT JOIN clm_claim_case ccc ON clme.id = ccc.clm_event_id
                    LEFT JOIN agr_agreement agr ON agr.id = ccc.agr_agreement_id
                    LEFT JOIN clm_ext_agreement cea ON ccc.id = cea.clm_claim_case_id
                WHERE
                    1=1
                GROUP BY clme.id
                         ,clme.vehicle_reg_numbers
                         ,clme.event_type_id
           ,clme.event_date_sortable
                HAVING 1=1       
            ) ) q
            WHERE vehicle_reg_numbers LIKE '%';
```

I change this query to:

```
select SCORE(1), id,
       agr_numbers,......
```

...........

```
WHERE CONTAINS (vehicle_reg_numbers, '%', 1) > 0
            ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC, id,
               agr_numbers,
               vehicle_reg_numbers;
```

And then I get error shown above. **I understand, that I need to put**

```
collect(distinct nvl(agr.agreement_number,cea.agreement_number)) as coll_names
```

**To GROUP BY, but I don't know how. Please help!** 
I really need to use CONTAINS, I read documentation and no luck. I tried many forms of CONTAINS, no luck. I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use agr.agreement_number and cea.agreement_number in `SELECT` if you don't add them in `GROUP BY` clause.
So try to change `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY clme.id
  ,clme.vehicle_reg_numbers
  ,clme.event_type_id
  ,clme.event_date_sortable
  ,agr.agreement_number
  ,cea.agreement_number
```

or use function on them like `MIN`, `MAX` or `SUM`

Comment: Hello! It doesn't work. Still getting same error shown above after adding line like You said. It works if LIKE, but not working with CONTAINS. But thanks for answer, I still need help.